# Track execution path without knowing entry point in visual studio

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, debugging

Can I track code from the debug perspective in Visual Studio 2017 without prior break points?
I'm working on a subproject in a WPF application which is devided into multiple files in multiple directories. Nobody knows the entry points nor the actual size of it. I know how I can access some of it's functionality from the GUI. Is there a possibility to jump from clicking a menue to the matching code snippet in Visual Studio?
If not, how does one track software execution paths that are divided heavily?

Answer (score 1):

You can track execution paths with my [Runtime Flow](https://vlasovstudio.com/runtime-flow/) extension. You can click a menu and immediately see what code was executed after that.